# javascript - add days to date and date format not working

Tags: javascript

I've a form with fields `.daysfromtoday` and `#datefromtoday`.

I would like to enter a number of days in .daysfromtoday and update #datefromtoday with the date yyyy-mm-dd format. (I know that there are other posts about this subject, but, if possible, I would like someone helps me with code I've written, to learn more)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="daysfromtoday" />
<input type="text" id="datefromtoday" name="delay" />
```

#### javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(".daysfromtoday").on('change', function(){//
    var waitdays = $( ".daysfromtoday" ).val(); //take value from field .daysfromtoday
    var enddate = new Date();
    enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + waitdays); 
    var yyyy = enddate.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (enddate.getMonth()+1).toString();
    var dd = enddate.getDate().toString();
    document.getElementById("datefromtoday").value = yyyy + '-'  + mm + '-'  + dd; //outuput      
 });  
});
```

**Problems: (and solutions)**

1. I get weird results: today is `2016-02-26`, if I enter 100, I get `2087-7-17`
2. The result format should have the 0 (zeros): 2016-03-08

Comment: I know it's not a proper answer to your question but this library is worth checking out, it makes dealing with dates much much easier : http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Try `var waitdays = parseInt($( ".daysfromtoday" ).val());` try to use `parseInt()` for your input...

Comment: @brso05 Thanks! Do you have any suggestion for points #2 and #3? Thanks!

Comment: @codeispoetry `if(mm < 10){monthFormatted = "0" + mm;}else{monthFormatted = "" + mm;}` then use `monthFormatted` in your output instead of `mm`. Same for day...Also get rid of the `.toString()` don't convert it to a `String` -> `var mm = (enddate.getMonth()+1);`

Comment: 3. `getElementsByClassName()` and `$(".whatever")` return a collection of elements...Maybe try this:`$(".daysfromtoday").on('change', function(){//
    var waitdays = $(this).val();`. `this` should be the element that triggered the `change` event.

Comment: @brso Sorry, but the if else solution doesn't seem o work... at least I can't.... see my edited question for the solution I adopted. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your questions. If you have an answer, post it below *as an answer*.

Answer (score 3):

You probably add `string` instead of `number` to the date. Try using `parseInt` function:

```
...
enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + parseInt(waitdays, 10));
...
```

Comment: Thanks Nhor I put the parsInt in the variable definition. Do you have any suggestion for points #2 and #3? Thanks!

Comment: 2) Instead of using `getDate`, `getMonth` and `getFullYear` I suggest you used a `substring` of `toISOString` like this: `enddate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)` then you get `string` like for example `"2016-02-26"`

Comment: 3) Using `getElementsByClassName` will return an array of results, because there can possibly be more than 1 element for given class, so if you are 100% sure there is only one, refer to it as `document.getElementsByClassName("datefromtoday")[0]`

Comment: Thanks for #3.        #2 works, but not for me, because it gives me the UTC, different from my time. Thanks!